# Criar barra de progresso com a hover() do jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, html5, progress-bar

Preciso criar uma barra de progresso enquanto meu cursor estiver em cima de uma imagem.
Se o cursor sair, então preciso que o progresso fique zerado para repetir o processo caso o cursor volte em cima da imagem.
Quando chegar no 100% vou abrir um modal.

Alguma idéia?

Comment: JavaScript, se procurar na web vai encontrar vários exemplos desse tipo de interação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode utilizar a função [`hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) para obter o evento de quando o ponteiro do mouse entrar/sair do elemento:

```js
$(function(){
  
  var interval,
      progress = $('progress'),
      INTERVAL_DELAY = 50;
  
  
  // "mouse in"
  progress.hover(function(){
  
    interval = setInterval(function(){
      progress.val(progress.val()+1);
      
      if(progress.val() === 100){
        console.log('Modal!');
        clearInterval(interval);
      } 
      
    }, INTERVAL_DELAY);
    
  // "mouse out"  
  }, function(){
  
    clearInterval(interval);
    progress.val(0);
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<progress min='0' max='100' value='0'>
```

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado amigo!